# How long will it take for a measurable change in mass (corrosion) in an iron copper corrosion cell to happen?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I am planning to do an experiment, in which I will test the affect of salt concentration on corrosion rate. Would there be a relationship? How long would it take for rust to form, that could be scrapped off and corrosion rate measured?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get any measurements, you would probably need to leave the coupon in the solution for about a week or so.

To see the difference due to the salt concentration differences, I would recommend going even longer, probably at least 2-3 weeks.